# running PYTHON from VIM at linux terminal

Tags: vim

Im from Linux-Ubuntu: Im new at coding, I started to use VIM to code in PYTHON so ===> is there any way I could select a chunk of code and then with  execute it in linux terminal and then with an enter return to VIM. Sorry for my english writing

Comment: looks like you want to make vim your shell

Comment: If you're interested in Vim, do check out [vi.se]!

Comment: There's also a QuickRun plugin to quickly run selected text or a file with some command: https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun/blob/master/doc/quickrun.txt

Answer (score 3):

Select the block of text by pressing `V` and moving around:

[image]

Now use `:w !python3` (or `python`, as the case may be):

[image]

This calls `python3` and passes the selected text to the standard input. So, if your code makes use of stdin, this won't work well. Naturally, this won't get you far. For running entire files, you can use `:!python3 %` or `:!python %`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it this way**

Go into visual mode in vim press: `V`

Select the text you want to execute

Type `:w test.py` ( creating a python script in the folder you're in)

Type `:!python test.py`

And press enter to return to vim